# ubuntu cannot shutdown without plugging usb device

Tags: usb, shutdown, reboot

I use samsung laptop series 5 and install Ubuntu 12.04 LTE.

But I found that I cannot shutdown the system, it will close the OS but still restart it, just like reboot the system.

Recently, I found that if I plug a usb device (usb flash or CD-ROM), I can shutdown the system successfully.

I don't know why and I try Lubuntu 14.04 live cd, there are some condition. Can anyone tell me how come or how can I find information that I need to solve this probelm, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a BIOS-related issue, can you try:

1. Edit the grub configuration file with: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Add `acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\"` kernel parameter into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line.
    So it should be changed from:
    
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
   To:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\""`
3. And run `sudo update-grub` to make this modification take effect.
4. Shutdown without USB devices plugged.

Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1288161

Comment: I try, but it still reboot, I'm not sure the problem is in OS or BIOS or Hardware(that I cannot fix by myself), but really thank you for replying